# Notification API - MDN - Showing Desktop notification based on each tab opened

Tags: javascript, browser, notifications, mozilla

Recently I was developing Desktop Notification for my application, after all got successfully working, what I noticed was, it shows number of notifications for a one particular incident which is equal to opened number of tabs.

Followed the instructions of MDN,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification

What could be possibly done to avoid notifications like that? no matter how many tabs are opened, for a one particular incident I want only one desktop notification to be shown.

Comment: Use the *window.postMessage* method to check for other instances running...

Comment: would you mind clarifying it a bit ?
FYI: In my case each window is getting subscribed to the same MessageBus channel, inside that I'm generating the Desktop notifications